# 内部DNSを設定してiphoneから設定したDNSを使ってWEBアクセスしたい

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

下記のサイトを参考に内部DNSの設定をおこないました。

http://qiita.com/mechamogera/items/574de60310fb19e088ca

このページの最後の設定でiphoneからのWEBアクセスがあるのですが、

> •iphoneから確認 ◦wifiの設定でDNSを[DNSサーバのPublicIP]にしてwifi接続 => safari>でwww.example.com確認
>   => hogeee表示

この設定の前にSSIDの設定はどこにすればよいでしょうか。
初歩的な質問ですが、ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: iPhoneの設定以前に、このサイトの設定のままだと[オープンリゾルバ](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/dns/openresolver/)になっていると思います。至急確認してください。意味がわからないのであれば速やかにnamedを停止してください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。namedの停止の方おこないました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIDは無線LANの接続に必要な情報ですので お使いの無線アクセスポイントを確認してみてください。職場でしたらネットワークの管理者に聞くと良いと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ネットワーク管理者に聞いてみます。